# jquery click tracking is acting a little strage

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, jquery

On some links on my HTML page I have a special CSS class, that when clicked, I make a ajax call to a click.aspx page and track the click.

```
<a href="..." class="click" id="blah-1">blah-1</a>


$(".click").bind("click", function() {

          $.get("/click.aspx?&source=" + $(this).attr("id"));

});
```

So what is happening is the value of source, after clicking a few links (that open in a new window) becomes:

```
source=blah1
```

then it becomes

```
source=blah1,blah2
```

Comment: Would an HTTP post be more appropriate for this than a get?  At least it would keep URL from getting cluttered.  You could write a custom, light weight handler that just returns HTTP status 200 when the click has been recorded instead of running a page through the full page life cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to change it to:

```
$(".click")each(function(i) {
     $(this).bind("click", function() {
          $.get("/click.aspx?&source=" + $(this).attr("id"));
     });
});
```

so that each is processed separately...

Comment: I tried that, I think the issue is that the page doesn't load for some of the clicks, since the clicks open in a new browser??